# Node-Red Subflow Password Field

Tags: node-red, password-protection

I wonder if it is possible to add a password field for a Node-Red subflow environment variable. I want to hand over user and password but be sure, that the password is not visible and also not copied when copying the flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in the current release.

The ability to identify a Subflow property as a credential-type field will come in the next release - 1.1.0.

Comment: Hmmm ... not the answer I hoped to get ... Thank You.